# Magento 1.4.0.1 create and populate new attribute value for almost all products

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I am trying to figure out how I might be able to do this - possibly in the mysql database, but I'm not sure of all the tables involved, so daren't go much further?

I have added an attribute called "condition" to the defaul attribute set.
I need to populate that attribute value for every product, but the admin system requires me to fill in many other attributes if I try to bulk update them using the admin form. This can't happen as "description" is different for every product, obviously.

So, can someone tell me how I might populate this attribute value with the value "new" for every product in my database?

Realistically, I can change this attribute value for the number of products that need a different value "used", but if the update could be filtered on SKU, I can make it work right first time. I think!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The programming approach is to save the following script in your Magento folder and execute it by visiting the address directly. It might be slow but that doesn't matter if it's only going to be run once and then deleted afterwards.

```
<?php

require 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
foreach ($products as $product) {
    // replace IS_NEW with a test perhaps using $product->getSku()
    $product->setCondition(IS_NEW ? 'new' : 'used')
            ->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a programming answer so perhaps not suitable for Stack Overflow but there are a number of workarounds.

You could export all products to Excel, bulk update many rows at once then re-inport. Use [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpwebsite/magmi/) if you have many products.

There are some extensions which let you update many attributes at once. This [Mass Actions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mass-product-actions.html) is expensive but gives you an idea what might be available if you search.

As much as I loathe desktop applications for web services there is [Store Manager](http://www.mag-manager.com/) which specialises in bulk actions.

Comment: Thanks, I can use Mass Actions for other stuff definitely. I will see if it helps with this issue. If not, I need to figure out the structure at the database level and do it that way I guess. Thanks for the pointer!